# How to play a system sound from a UWP method

Tags: audio, uwp

Hi totally confused here!  I can't figure out how to get my method to play a system sound (beep) on an error.  The system.media class is not available.  So I am totally lost!

```
 private void SubmitApplicant_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(attendenceManagment.Applicant))
            attendenceManagment.CheckApplicant();
        else  
        //play a beep
        ;
    }
```

Working code:

XAML Tag

```
 <MediaElement x:Name="myMediaElement"/>
```

Code behind

```
   private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(attendenceManagment.Applicant))
            attendenceManagment.CheckApplicant();
        else
        {
            myMediaElement.Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Windows   Error.wav");
            myMediaElement.Play();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider using [MediaElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt187272.aspx), but you'll need to do some magic to hide it and also to load beep sound to resources yourself.

As far as I know, Beep is not available for mobile.